# Building Boost (1.58) with Clang (3.8) and Android NDK r14b

Tags: c++, boost, android-ndk, clang++

I try to build boost 1.58 for android NDK r14b with clang 3.8. I have it working corretcly with gcc but it is not the case with clang.

By running the following command (it is a single example on program_options lib) :

```
"androidNDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++" 
-c 
-x c++ 
-std=c++11 
--stdlib=libc++ 
-mthumb 
-Os 
-O2 
-g 
-Wno-unused-local-typedefs 
-O3 
-Wno-inline 
-Wall 
--sysroot=androidNDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm 
-I"androidNDK/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include"
-D_GLIBCXX__PTHREADS 
-D__arm__ 
-D_REENTRANT 
-D__ANDROID__ 
-DANDROID 
-pthread 
-std=c++11 
--stdlib=libc++ 
-mthumb 
-fno-strict-aliasing 
-DBOOST_ALL_NO_LIB=1 
-DBOOST_TEST_NO_MAIN 
-DNDEBUG 
-D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 
-D_LITTLE_ENDIAN 
-I"." 
-o "bin.v2\libs\program_options\build\clang-linux-android\release\link-static\runtime-link-static\target-os-linux\threadapi-pthread\threading-multi\config_file.o" "libs\program_options\src\config_file.cpp"
```

But I get some errors on the signal.h file :

```
clang++.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mthumb'
clang++.exe: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-mthumb'
In file included from libs\program_options\src\config_file.cpp:8:
In file included from .\boost/program_options/config.hpp:10:
In file included from .\boost/config.hpp:57:
In file included from .\boost/config/platform/linux.hpp:74:
In file included from .\boost/config/posix_features.hpp:18:
In file included from androidNDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/include\unistd.h:34:
In file included from androidNDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/include\sys/select.h:35:

androidNDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/include\signal.h:86:18: error: expected ';' at

      end of declaration list
    sighandler_t sa_handler;
                 ^
androidNDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/include\asm/signal.h:101:22: note: expanded
      from macro 'sa_handler'
#define sa_handler _u._sa_handler
                     ^
In file included from libs\program_options\src\config_file.cpp:8:
In file included from .\boost/program_options/config.hpp:10:
In file included from .\boost/config.hpp:57:
In file included from .\boost/config/platform/linux.hpp:74:
In file included from .\boost/config/posix_features.hpp:18:
In file included from androidNDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/include\unistd.h:34:
In file included from androidNDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/include\sys/select.h:35:

androidNDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/include\signal.h:87:12: error: expected ')'
    void (*sa_sigaction)(int, struct siginfo*, void*);
           ^
androidNDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/include\asm/signal.h:102:24: note: expanded
      from macro 'sa_sigaction'
#define sa_sigaction _u._sa_sigaction
                       ^
androidNDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/include\signal.h:87:10: note: to match this
      '('
    void (*sa_sigaction)(int, struct siginfo*, void*);
         ^
androidNDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/include\signal.h:87:12: error: duplicate
      member '_u'
    void (*sa_sigaction)(int, struct siginfo*, void*);
           ^
androidNDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/include\asm/signal.h:102:22: note: expanded
      from macro 'sa_sigaction'
#define sa_sigaction _u._sa_sigaction
                     ^
androidNDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/include\signal.h:86:18: note: previous
      declaration is here
    sighandler_t sa_handler;
                 ^
androidNDK/platforms/android-24/arch-arm/usr/include\asm/signal.h:101:20: note: expanded
      from macro 'sa_handler'
#define sa_handler _u._sa_handler
                   ^
3 errors generated.
```

Is there anybody who has already did something like this or could see something wrong ?

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug. Could you file one with repro instructions? https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues

Answer (score 0):

So it finally worked for me. 
I realized that those errors on signal.h were because the target of my compiler was not really defined. I wanted to build boost for arm 32 bits but in the "performing configuration checks", it was :
- 32 bit : no
- 64 bit : yes
- arm    : yes

So, I changed my user-config.jam in my boost folder to :

```
import os ; 
androidNDKRoot = E:/androidNDK ; # put the relevant path  
using clang : android : 
    $(androidNDKRoot)/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/bin/clang++  : 
    <compileflags>--sysroot=$(androidNDKRoot)/platforms/android-21/arch-arm 
    <compileflags>-I$(androidNDKRoot)/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include 
    <compileflags>-I$(androidNDKRoot)/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++abi/include 
    <compileflags>-I$(androidNDKRoot)/sources/android/support/include 
    <compileflags>-g 
    <compileflags>-Os 
    <compileflags>-O2 
    <compileflags>--target=armv7a-none-linux-androideabi 
    ;
```

It seems that clang doesn't have options like  and  in gcc, so I added their common absolute path in PATH variable :

```
set PATH=%PATH%;E:\androidNDK\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\arm-linux-androideabi\bin\
```

And to test a build (for example : atomic), I executed from my boost folder :

```
b2.exe --user-config=tools\build\src\build\user-config.jam target-os=android toolset=clang-android link=static runtime-link=static variant=debug threading=multi -q -a -j6 --with-atomic
```